# How does swagger-codegen automatically generate applications and dockerfiles?

Tags: swagger, code-generation, swagger-codegen, openapi

I want to clarify the generation process of applications and dockerfiles. In order to understand this, I have drawn a graph to represent the flow based on my understanding of the documentation and source code. I will be glad if someone takes a look and corrects or approves the schema.  The flow tries to describe the generation of `NodeJS` application from a `Java` application.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swagger-codegen doesn't generate the template files, it uses the template files that are written by the (insert language here) codegen developer(s).

I assume the schema you've drawn is the flow of the NodeJSCodeGen because not every supported language generates a dockerfile.

Personally I would replace the Java microservice -> generates Model with OpenAPI specification -> Code Generator, as the generator uses the specification. It doesn't matter if you generated it from from a micro service or if you went with the API first approach.

Comment: yeah also discovered that the dockerfile are not always generated, but for the times when generation occurs, do you know how it works ? Also, I assumed or read from somewhere that the templates are generated when the repository is build, e.g. you clone and build and then the templates are generated into a specified directory. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would assume that there's a template along the lines of dockerfile.moustache but don't quote me on that.

I don't have alot of experience with docker yet so I don't know if it needs access to alot of template variables.  I would recommend have a look in the opensource project for the language you're using:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen 
and
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources